# Chisel: Define functions that operate on user defined Bundle types

Tags: scala, function, chisel, register-transfer-level

I have a Bundle type containing a 2D vec:

```
def myBundle extends Bundle {
  val v = Vec(4, Vec( 4, UInt()))
  // etc ...
}
```

I want to define a hardware generating function which operates on `myBundle` and returns a `myBundle` like so:

```
def elementwise_add(x: myBundle, y: myBundle): MyBundle {
  val result = new MyBundle
  for(i <- 0 until 4)
    for(j <- 0 until 4)
      result.v(i)(j) = x.v(i)(j) + y.v(i)(j)
   return result
}
```

However if I define this, Chisel throws an error during compile that: "value update is not a member of chisel3.Vec[chisel3.UInt] did you mean updated?"

How should I define this function (and others like it) so that it generates the hardware I am trying to generate here?

(Note: Vec here is important in this case because I want to be able to address myBundle.v with hardware signals)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
def elementwise_add(x: myBundle, y: myBundle): MyBundle {
  val result = new MyBundle
  for(i <- 0 until 4)
    for(j <- 0 until 4)
      result.v(i)(j) = x.v(i)(j) + y.v(i)(j)
   return result
}
```

to:

```
def elementwise_add(x: myBundle, y: myBundle): MyBundle {
  val result = new MyBundle
  for(i <- 0 until 4)
    for(j <- 0 until 4)
      result.v(i)(j) := x.v(i)(j) + y.v(i)(j)
   return result
}
```

(use chisel assign(:=) operator rather than Scala =)
And make sure you are using Chisel 5.0 or greater (I was on 3.5.6) and this code works as expected.